# select combobox item in website using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to select a combo box item in a website using c#

i open a website using a web browser

my code is

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("xxxxx.com");
HtmlElementCollection Col2;
Col2 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
            foreach (HtmlElement ele in Col2)
            {
                if (ele.Id == "country")
                {
                   ele.InnerText=("palestine");
                }
            }
```

where is Palestine is one of the items in the combo box.
any help please

Comment: You should post at least the html page, otherwise it's impossible help you

Comment: i just need the right way to select element from the combo box

Comment: But we don't know where the select item is

Comment: ok here is the site https://courses.edx.org/register
i need to chose palestine from the Country combobox 
thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").SetAttribute("value", "palestine");
```

or

```
webBrowser1.Document
           .GetElementsByTagName("select")
           .Children.GetElementsByName("option")[1] // Get option by index
           .SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: thanks that works but how to do to click the value palestine

Comment: i mean that like if i clicked the value

Comment: See the alternative way. Otherwise you would have to invoke a function.

Comment: can you please tell me how to invoke an item in the combo box